# Best messaging medium for real-time SOA applications?

Tags: web-services, architecture, jms

I'm working on a real time application implemented using in a SOA-style (read loosely coupled components connected via some messaging protocol - JMS, MQ or HTTP).

The architect who designed this system opted to use JMS to connect the components.  This system is real time so there no need to queue up messages should one component fail (the transaction will simply time out).  Further, there is no need for guaranteed delivery or rollback.

In this instance, is there any benefit to using JMS over something like an HTTP web service (speed, resource footprint, etc)?

One thing that I'm thinking is since the JMS approach requires us to set a thread pool size (the number of components listening to a JMS topic/queue), wouldn't a HTTP service be a better fit since this additional configuration is not needed (a new thread is created for each HTTP request making the application scalable to an "unlimited" number of requests until the server runs out of resources).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't disagree with the points made by S.Lott at all, but here are a couple of points to consider regarding HTTP web services:

- Your clients only need to know how to communicate via HTTP - a protocol well supported by just about every modern langauge in one form or another. JMS, though popular,  is more specialist than HTTP, and so restricts the languages your interconnected systems can use. Perhaps not an issue for your system at the moment, but will you need to plug in other systems later that might struggle to support JMS connectivity?
- Standards like WSDL and SOAP which you could levarage for your services are well supported by many langauges and there are plenty of tools around that will generate code to implement both ends of the pipeline (client and server) for you from a WSDL file, reducing the amount of dev you'll have to do. These standards also make it relatively simple to define and publish the specification of the data you'll be passing between your systems, something you'll presumably have to do by hand using a queueing technology like JMS.
- On the downside, as pointed out by S.Lott, JMS gives you functionality that you throw away using the (stateless) HTTP protocol: guaranteed ordering & reliability; monitoring; scalability; etc. Are you sure you don't need these, and won't need these going forward?

Great question, btw.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's really dependent on the situation. Where I work, we support Remoting, JMS, MQ, HTTP, and sFTP. We are implementing a middleware appliance that speaks Remoting, JMS, MQ, and HTTP, and a software middleware component that speaks JMS, MQ, and HTTP.

As sgreeve alluded to above, standards help us become flexible, but proprietary formats allow more functionality.

In a nutshell, I'd say use HTTP for stateless calls (which could end up meeting almost all of your needs), and whatever proprietary formats you need for stateful calls. If you work in a big enterprise, a hardware appliance is usually a great fit as middleware: Lightning fast compression, encryption, transformation, and translation, with very low total cost of ownership.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about your requirements, but you may be overlooking Manageability, Flexibility and Performance.

JMS allows you to monitor and manage the queue.  These are features HTTP lacks, and you'd have to build rather than buy from a vendor.

Also, There are queues and topics in JMS, allowing multiple subscribers to a single publisher.  Not possible in HTTP.

While you may not need those things in release 1.0, you might want them in the future.

Also, JMS may be able to use other transport mechanisms like named sockets, which reduces the overheads if there isn't all that socket negotiation going on with (almost) every request.

Answer (score 1):

If you go down the HTTP route and you want to support more than one machine or some kind of reliability - you are going to need a load balancer capable of discovering the available web servers and loading requests across them - then failing over to another web server if a particular box/process dies. Clients making HTTP requests are also going to have to deal with servers failing and retrying operations in some loop.

This is one of the main features of a message queue - reliable load balancing with failover and loose coupling among the producers and consumers without them having to include retry logic - so your client or server code doesn't have to worry about this kinda thing. This is totally separate to whether or not you want message persistence or want to use ACID transactions to produce/consume messages (which can be very handy BTW).

If you focus just on the server side using Java - whether Servlets or MessageListener/MDBs they are kinda similar either way really. The difference is the load balancer.

So maybe the question should really be - is a JMS broker easier to setup & work with than setting up your DNS/NAT/IP/HTTP load balancer infrastructure?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by real-time... Neither JMS nor HTTP in my opinion support "real-time" applications well, meaning they cannot offer predictable/deterministic performance nor properly prioritize flows in the presence of contention.

Part of it is that these technologies are built on top of TCP which serializes all traffic into a single FIFO meaning that different traffic flows cannot be easily prioritized. Moreover TCP timers are not easily controlled resulting unpredictable blocking and timeouts... For this reason many streaming applications use UDP instead of TCP as an underlying protocol.

Another problem with JMS is that typical implementations use a broker that centralizes message dispatch. This is not the best architecture to get deterministic performance.

If you are looking for a middleware that can offer you the kind of reliability guarantees and publish-subscribe semantics you get with JMS, but was developed to fit the real-time application domain I recommend you take a look at the OMG Data-Distribution Service (DDS). See dds.omg.org  and this article I wrote arguing why DDS is the best middleware to implement a real-time SOA. http://soa.sys-con.com/node/467488